# androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver not found

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx

I am having a problem where my build cannot find one of the androidx classes, specifically:

```
androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver
```

Here are my gradle deps:

```
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.0.0"
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0"
```

I don't have any other problems getting androidx classes, just this one.

I have tried to invalidate caches in android studio and restart with no luck.  Also a build clean as well as a gradle sync.

I verified here:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate

The mapping of that class from the support library to androidx:

> android.arch.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver ->
>   androidx.lifecycle.DefaultLifecycleObserver

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

I think that's because you're missing one dependency:

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"
```

Get the latest version of `lifecycle-common-java8` [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/androidx.lifecycle/lifecycle-common-java8)

See the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/Lifecycle):

> If you use Java 8 Language, then observe events with
> DefaultLifecycleObserver. To include it you should add
> "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:" to your
> build.gradle file.

Comment: YES!  Thank you so much.